# Is there a way to separate xml namespaces to the "owner" tag?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This is my first time here and I don't know how to explain the problem, so I'm gonna show in examples

I have three classes, the parent that contains two childs

**Parent**

```java
package com.teste.jaxb.p1;

// imports

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parent {
    private ChildOne childOne;
    private ChildTwo childTwo;

    // getters and setters

}
```

**ChildOne**

```java
package com.test.jaxb.p1;

// imports

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildOne {
    private String description;

    // getters and setters
}
```

in the same package (p1) I have the package-info class with namespace="http://test.com"

**ChildTwo**

```java
package com.test.jaxb.p2;

// imports

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ChildTwo {
    private String name;

    // getters and setters

}
```

with package-info namespace="http://www.second.com"

when I run

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne();
        childOne.setDescription("Description");
        ChildTwo childTwo = new ChildTwo();
        childTwo.setName("Test");
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setChildOne(childOne);
        parent.setChildTwo(childTwo);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.marshal(parent, writer);
        String xml = writer.toString();
        xml = xml.replaceAll(" *standalone=\"(yes|no)\" *", "");
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
```

it returns

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parent xmlns="http://test.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.second.com"><childOne><description>Description</description></childOne><childTwo><ns2:name>Test</ns2:name></childTwo></parent>
```

is there a way to make it returns like that?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parent xmlns="http://test.com"><childOne xmlns="http://test.com"><description>Description</description></childOne><childTwo xmlns="http://www.second.com"><name>Test</name></childTwo></parent>
```

Comment: I don't think what you want is easily doable out of the box. [The user guide](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#marshalling-interaction-between-marshalling-and-dom) gives some hints on why JAXB behaves as it does. One way you might create such a result would be to first marshal `childTwo` afterwards the whole parent, including its children, and then use a transformer to update the output of the parent XML to your desired output, i.e. by removing the namespace in the parent for `childTwo` and replace childTwo (and its contents) with the output of childTwo's XML